# Date seems to be giving me an hour late

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, date

I'm trying to get the hours from a Date value from a Lambda Function which has the date set as `2018-05-28 21:37:27.261 (+01:00)` for a value of

```
time    2018-05-29T14:00:00+01:00
```

When I do a `console.log(time.getHours())` I get 13 instead of 14. I tried using `getUTCHours()` as that was universal but it seems to be the same. I don't understand what is causing it and don't want to be adding a +1 hour.

Hope some clarification can be given in this.

Thanks

Comment: maybe your local machine and your server is in different timezone

Comment: Hmm, that's really annoying. I will try and make the DialogFlow client and Lambda as close as I can for the time and date and will let you know what I find.

Comment: It's not clear to me where your confusion lies... 2018-05-29T14:00:00+01:00 == 2018-05-29T13:00:00Z.  The correct hours value **is** 13, because the timestamp has an offset of `+01:00`.